# fgets() printing the last line twice in C

Tags: c, fopen, fgets

I was supposed to open a file from a command-line argument and print the values in it. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  float num;
  char const* const filename=argv[1];
  FILE* file=fopen(filename,"r");
  char line[256];
  int j=0;

  while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file)){

    for( j=0; j<2; j++ )
    {
      if(j == 0)
      {
           fscanf(file, "%f", &num);
           printf("%f \t", num);
      }
      else if(j == 1)
      {
          fscanf(file, "%f", &num);
          printf("%f \n", num);
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

This is what I’d like to get as output:

```html
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

This is what I’m actually getting:

```html
1 1
2 2
3 3
3 3
```

I don't get what's happening here.

Comment: integer values
ive given here. take a look.

Comment: An extra empty line in your file would explain such a behavior. Try to test the return value of [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/). It will tell you the number of items successfully read.

Comment: i have tested the return value of fscanf(). now my problem solved. But new problem is first line is not printing. :(

Answer (score 1):

I done two changes in your code.

change

```
fscanf(file,"%f",&num);
```

into

```
sscanf(line,"%f",&num);// here
```

you are reading the input in loop, but you are getting the value from the file pointer. so first line will be skipped. Then make the test case in while opening the file stream.

```
if ( file == NULL)  { 
     perror("fopen");
     return;      
}
```

Try this code, I done the above changes only,

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    float num;
    char const* const filename=argv[1];
    FILE* file=fopen(filename,"r");
    if ( file == NULL)  { 
       perror("fopen");
      return;      
    }
    char line[256];
    int j=0;
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file) != NULL){
            for(j=0; j<2;j++)
            {
                    if(j==0)
                    {
                            sscanf(line,"%f",&num);
                            printf("%f \t",num);
                    }
                    if(j==1)
                    {
                            sscanf(line,"%f",&num);
                            printf("%f \n",num);
                    }
            }
    }
    fclose(file);
 }
```

output:

```
 130.000000     130.000000
 210.000000     210.000000
 650.000000     650.000000
 324.000000     324.000000
```

Comment: @AdamRose are you tried this? It will give you the answer for your question posted in comment!

Comment: its returning the same value twice bro

Comment: example like this
130 210
650 324
but output
130 130
650 650

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you read the line with `fgets` then begin reading on the next line with `fscanf`. In other words after `fgets (line, LMAX-1, file)` The file position indicator is at the **end** of line 1. You then `fscanf(file, "%f", &num);` (which skips the `'\n'` at the end of line 1 and read the value for line 2). You want:

```
while (fgets (line, LMAX-1, file)) {

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            sscanf (line, "%f", &num);
            printf ("%f \t", num);
        } else if (j == 1) {
            sscanf (line, "%f", &num);
            printf ("%f \n", num);
        }
    }
}
```

Then output becomes:

```
./bin/dbllast dat/dbllast.txt
1.000000        1.000000
2.000000        2.000000
3.000000        3.000000
```